# Elasticsearch, which path for elasticsearch.keystore is used?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand why I get 401.

Steps taken:

- created a elasticsearch.keystore
- add the `bootstrap.password` successfully, with `cat ~/.elk.secret | /opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add -x 'bootstrap.password'`
- Since I've **multiple instances running**, I **move** it in the **new conf directory**

but now I get 401:

```
 curl -X GET 'https://elastic:myFancyPass@myServer:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' -k
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
        "header" : {
          "WWW-Authenticate" : [
            "Bearer realm=\"security\"",
            "ApiKey",
            "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_cluster/health?pretty]",
    "header" : {
      "WWW-Authenticate" : [
        "Bearer realm=\"security\"",
        "ApiKey",
        "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
      ]
    }
  },
  "status" : 401
}
```

My understanding is that this error can be caused by two things:

- wrong password (which I doubt it's my case)
- wrong elasticsearch.file

How do I find which **elasticsearch.keystore it is loading**?

Running `rootLogger.level = debug` didn't help. I feel it would be great getting a confirmation such as `/opt/elasticsearch/instance2/conf/elasticsearch.keystore`

Comment: From the docs: _elasticsearch.keystore file is created alongside the elasticsearch.yml file._

Comment: How can I find out which path is actually loaded into my elasticsearch?